# What is this object in Batman v Superman Ultimate Edition

Tags: dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In Batman v Superman, when Wonder Woman is viewing the contents of the encrypted drive, she comes across a journal entry of **Dr. Silas Stone**, who, according to the comics, was a cybernetics expert at **Star Labs**. Also, he happens to be the father of Cyborg (Victor Stone), according to several sources, for example, [this one](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/cyborg/4005-2388/):

> Victor Stone is the son of Silas and Elinore Stone, two STAR Labs
>   scientists intent on using their research to improve mankind. Silas
>   and Elinore scientific adventures often estranged their son, as they
>   would sometime dedicate more time and toward their work, oppose to
>   him. The two even used their son as a test subject for
>   intelligence-boosting experimentation. While the successful experiment
>   granted Victor a genius-level intellect, he resented his parents for
>   treating him more like a lab subject oppose to a son.

So, when I saw the cameo in Batman v Superman: Ultimate Edition, I understood it was Cyborg's origin story. However, I saw this object, which Dr. Stone referred to as **US GOV Object 6-19-82**:

[image]

I tried researching what the object was, but I could not find out. I found [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/trivia) that the object attaches itself to Victor and he becomes Cyborg:

> During the Cyborg clip Dr. Stone mentions he has "US GOV object
>   6-19-82" which attaches itself to Victor Stone to create Cyborg. The
>   number 6-19-82 is a reference to the comic Tales of the New Teen
>   Titans #1 (June 1982): "Cyborg".

**My Question: What is that mysterious object (US GOV Object 6-19-82). can somebody identify it. Where did it come from.**

Comment: Is this only specific to the Ultimate Edition or was it depicted in the theatrical release, too?

Comment: that scene's in the theatrical release. However, the same object appears later in an extended-cut-only scene.

Comment: The movie [Justice League: War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_War) is basically all about the Mother Box(es)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That object is [Mother box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Box).

Even in comics his origin is related to Mother Box in The New 52

> Later Victor appears at S.T.A.R. Labs where his father works. The
>   scientists appear to be working on the Mother Box that Superman came
>   in contact with from the Parademon. Victor engages in another argument
>   with his father and tells him that the scouts were there to give him
>   full scholarships to college. When asking if his father will ever
>   appear at any of his games, his father replies "No." Just then the
>   Mother Box explodes, killing the other scientists and destroying most
>   of Victor's body while Victor's father looks on in horror. Silas
>   does everything he can for Victor's survival. He along with Sarah
>   Charles, and T. O. Morrow go in "The Red Room" in S.T.A.R. labs which
>   contains every piece of technology from around the world. Silas
>   attempts to treat Victor with something that has never been attempted
>   before and he is seen injecting Victor with some type of nanites and
>   having Dr. Morrow put the robotic pieces on Victor (devices such as: a
>   Promethean skin graft, Doctor William Magnus' responsometer, Anthony
>   Ivo's A-maze operating system, The classified and prototypical B-maze
>   operating system and Ryan Choi's White Dwarf Stabilizer). Vic's life
>   is saved and the energies from the motherbox are incorporated into his
>   new form as Cyborg. This allows Victor to access the vast New Gods
>   data library and discover Darkseid's true invasion plans

Even in animated film [Justice League: War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_War), which is based on The New 52. Cyborg was normal human before he got contacted to Mother Box and transform into Cyborg.

And from the synopsis of  [Justice League (2017 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_%282017_film%29#Cast):

> Additionally, it was revealed that Steppenwolf will be the main antagonist of the film. Darkseid's uncle, in command of Darkseid's army of Parademons, Steppenwolf is charged with hunting down the three Mother Boxes on Earth, located in Atlantis, Themyscira and one which is now a part of the character Cyborg.

It is clear that Mother box is part of this version of cyborg too and Mother Box will play major part in future films too.

Mother box also appear in extended cut again with mysterious creature

Refer [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/56228/1190) for speculation about that creature.

Answer (score 8):

It's called a "Mother Box", and it's a pretty big deal in the DC universe. Not only does one appear in the Cyborg scene, as confirmed by the director:

> "That's the first glimpse of the Mother Box there," Snyder said, referring to the Cyborg scene in the film. "It was an agonizing birth." <sup>[src](http://www.vinereport.com/article/justice-league-movie-news-zack-snyder-confirms-mother-box-in-batman-v-superman-teases-bigger-role/9693.htm)</sup>

but there is another glimpse of one in a bonus scene that wasn't in the theatrical release. There is a deleted scene with Lex Luthor ([later released on the web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-MUzvASr8s), called "Communion") that shows Luthor meeting with an unnamed alien. This is a character named Steppenwolf, an emissary of Darkseid, and he's got three more Mother Boxes with him. Presumably, Darkseid will be the main villain in the upcoming *Justice League* movies.

Mother Boxes are somewhat like "living computers" -- they are part machine and part living being, they're sentient, and they're *very* powerful. The [list of things](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Mother_Box) a Mother Box has done in the comics is very long, and so far in the movies, we've seen one turn Victor Stone into Cyborg.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. It proved i am so slow ;D Anyways i didn't know about that official confirmation.