# Was Flash's message in Batman vs Superman for the event occured in Justice League?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, justice-league

Ok, so there were a lot of questions regarding Bruce's 'knightmare'/ visions and The Flash's message in *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice* most of which are answered [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52551/explanation-of-bruce-batmans-nightmares).

So, following the predictable resurrection of Superman in *Justice League*, I found the film's most impressive moment to be the reveal of Bruce and Alfred's 'Big Gun' - the use of Lois to snap Superman out of his post revival rage.

Is there any evidence to suggest that this was the future moment that Snyder's had in mind when planting the 'Lois Lane is the key... am I too early' message from The Flash in *BvS*, considering that he had not yet 'died' at that point, as despite Lois' involvement in the climax of the *BvS* showdown it was made unnecessarily clear that the whole 'Martha' thing was pivotal to snapping Bruce out of his bloodlust?

Comment: Didn't know about the "pop culture reference" name the dream was given. Today I learned, cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the plan was way bigger then what we saw in Justice League. From [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/justice-league-darkseid-killed-lois-lane-dceu/):

> As Snyder continued, he revealed that the Flash's warning to Bruce Wayne about Lois Lane being the key was central to this future. "Because Lois - and it's in the Justice League teaser; it wasn't in the movie apparently... it's this line where Bruce says, 'I was right here, and Barry Allen came to me and he said 'Lois Lane is the key.' And then [Wonder Woman] goes, 'She is to Superman; every heart has one.' And he goes, 'I think it's something more, something darker.' And what it means is that the thing that was darker was all about if Lois died, Superman would succumb to the Anti-Life, right? And Superman knew that somehow it was Bruce's responsibility to protect Lois, he would've been mad at him in this movie, and that's why he says, 'She was my world, and you took her from me."

For the elaborated answer, we nee dot say to WB #releasethesnydercut ;)

You can read more about Zack's version on [comicbook.com](https://comicbook.com/dc/2019/03/25/zack-snyders-original-justice-league-plans-deleted-post-credit-scene-revealed/).

Comment: Thanks to the flawed but undoubtable improvement on Justice League that was last weeks release of ZSJL this answer now not only makes sense but has actual cinematic context. A belated thanks again, Ankit x